# Encripción/Desencripción de datos en AES/DES/3DES en C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, encriptación

Estoy usando un IDE para un software especifico (Desarrollo de Programas para TPV) basado en Eclipse (me parece tiene una versión de Eclipse muy antigua o muy limitada) y necesito implementar los métodos de Encripción AES/DES/3DES "a mano" ya que por especificación del fabricante no puede usar por ejemplo OpenSSL el IDE. ¿Cómo podría implementarlos sin usar OpenSSL por mencionar alguna librería?

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! a que te referis con como implementarlos? tuviste algun problema en particular?

Comment: @gbianchi no, en realidad ya los he "implementado" usando por ejemplo OpenSSL, el problema es que este particular IDE la documentación dice que no soporta OpenSSL entonces necesito saber como implementarlos "a mano"

Comment: Pero el IDE es el entorno de desarrollo.. los que soportan o no esas cosas son los lenguajes.. no termino de comprender la pregunta.

Comment: @gbianchi el IDE que estoy usando a pesar de que usa como base Eclipse, le modificaron cosas para que fuera muy reducido su modo de uso, es decir, en otros IDE igual basados en Eclipse puedo añadir librerías y referenciarlas sin ningún problema, pero en este no me permite hacerlo. Por eso digo que esta limitado su uso.

Comment: ah perfecto.. y entonces, que ide estas usando?? porque para que algun experto pueda ayudarte, necesita saber que ide es.. con que este basado en eclipse no alcanza...

Comment: @gbianchi me parece es Eclipse Equinox, el IDE se llama IngeDev y es un software para desarrollo de programas para TPVs, lo que si me deja hacer según el fabricante es usar librerías estáticas o dinámicas (.a o .so por ejemplo)

Comment: @NoeCano me parece que tu pregunta es muy amplia. ¿Puedes [edit] la pregunta para hacerla mas específica? Por favor lee **[¿Qué tipo de preguntas debo evitar preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)**. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pongo esto como respuesta porque no sería legible como ristra de comentarios.

Al IDE le da igual las librerías que uses. El IDE no es más que una ayuda para la gestión del proyecto. Al IDE tienes que decirle que el proyecto tiene dependencias externas (que son las librerías en las que se apoya).

¿Que no tienes la librería de openssl compilada en tu IDE? No hay problema, como es una librería *open source* te bajas los fuentes, creas el proyecto correspondiente (atendiendo a las dependencias de la versión que te bajes) y la compilas.

Es así de *"fácil"*. Cuesta un poco más al principio pero es cuestión de cogerle el punto. Lo que más pierdes es tiempo, ya que hay librerías que pueden tardar horas en compilar.

**Resumiendo**

Lo que sucede con los IDE es que, si están especializados en trabajar con una versión de un compilador en concreto, pueden tener varias librerías de uso común ya precompiladas... pero si no tienes esas librerías y necesitas usarlas la opción que te queda es compilarlas personalmente... por lo demás el resto del trabajo es exactamente el mismo.